Battery Charging issue
I am looking for help to fix Battery issues in ubuntu 24.04 Budgie version.
I`m using Samsung Galaxy Book4 ( non-360 degree) model laptop.
I have downloaded and installed Ubuntu Budgie - 24.04 on my laptop after installation facing charging issue.
Suddenly, Laptop battery charging taking long time. While checking in the section of Battery power ( Showing approx 30+ hours for full battery charge)
If, I Power-off my laptop and charge then its hardly take 1hour and 30 Minutes to full charge.
I strongly feel recent time lots of packages auto updated by OS after that facing this issues.
initrd.img-6.8.0-39-generic (Current version)
Please help me to fix this issues.

Look at your system startup log (watch your kernel discover the hardware) with the terminal command sudo journalctl  -b 0. Pay particular attention to messages about "power" or "battery".

@waltinator - I have collected the errors
